# Pandas, new column containing value if key equals another column

Tags: pandas, dataframe

Apologies if the title didn't make sense, I found it difficult to explain in one line.

I have a data frame, two of the columns contain data like this:

```
Column 1
| Selection_id |
| --------     |
| 46660181     |
| 40115397     |
| 267698       |
| 34774        | 
| 449342       | 

Column 2

| Bsps | 
| -------- | 
| 46660181: 2.1, 40115397: 1.75, 267698: 3.15, 34774: 2.64, 449342: 3.9   |
```

What I need to do is create a new column containing the value from the bsps as long as the selection id matches the bsp key. So 46660181 would have 2.1 in the column next to it.
I hope that makes sense!

I don't have a great knowledge on Python or Pandas as I've not done it for long but I'll do my best to follow along!

Any help with this would be appreciated, thank you.

Comment: Not sure why you have a dict as a string, but you could use ast.literal_eval to convert it into dict and use that dict to map the Column 1.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming some things here... There are faster ways than `df.apply` if you want to restructure your initial data, but it works as long as your data is on the smaller end and doesn't need to scale.

```
import pandas

df = pd.DataFrame(dict(cola=[2,1,3], colb=[[{1:4},{2:5},{3:6}], [{1:4},{2:5},{3:6}],[{1:4},{2:5},{3:6}],],))

|    |   cola | colb                     |
|---:|-------:|:-------------------------|
|  0 |      2 | [{1: 4}, {2: 5}, {3: 6}] |
|  1 |      1 | [{1: 4}, {2: 5}, {3: 6}] |
|  2 |      3 | [{1: 4}, {2: 5}, {3: 6}] |
```

solution:

```
df['val'] = df.apply(lambda row: [x.get(row.cola) for x in row.colb if x.get(row.cola) is not None][0], axis=1)

|    |   cola | colb                     |   val |
|---:|-------:|:-------------------------|------:|
|  0 |      2 | [{1: 4}, {2: 5}, {3: 6}] |     5 |
|  1 |      1 | [{1: 4}, {2: 5}, {3: 6}] |     4 |
|  2 |      3 | [{1: 4}, {2: 5}, {3: 6}] |     6 |
```